# How do ranged unarmed attacks work in Pathfinder 2e?

Tags: ranged-attack, pathfinder-2e, unarmed-combat

I was looking at the Leshy Ancestry feats and found one where you make a ranged unarmed attack called [Seedpod](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1041). I was wondering, how does a ranged unarmed attack work?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: You should probably expand on what about ranged unarmed attacks you think don't work, or aren't obvious, or which invoked rules you don't understand how work. Detailing the problem means it can be addressed better.

Comment: Agreed with Someone_Evil. I'd love to answer this question, but I'm unsure what exactly you want to know. Are you having problems with range increments? Figuring out what to add to the attack roll (or questions about a specific bonus)? Applying a certain feat to the attack? ... etc.

Comment: Perhaps I should try to clarify the question or ask a similar one? I believe the individual is interested how attack and damage rolls are handled.

Answer (score 2):

## Ranged unarmed attacks work similarly to ranged attacks

According to the unarmed attack rolls, an unarmed attack works largely the same as a weapon attack. Likewise, a ranged unarmed attack would work like a weapon ranged attack.

### Attack & Damage Rolls

You calculate attack and damage rolls of a ranged unarmed attack as you would with a ranged weapon, as indicated by page 278 of the core rulebook (emphasis mine).

> #### Unarmed Attacks
>
> Almost all characters start out trained in unarmed attacks. You can Strike with your fist or another body part, **calculating your attack and damage rolls in the same way you would with a weapon.** Unarmed attacks can belong to a weapon group (page 280), and they might have weapon traits (page 282).

Attack and damage rolls with a ranged weapon use the following calculations.

> Ranged attack modifier = Dexterity modifier + proficiency bonus + other bonuses + penalties
> ...
> Ranged damage roll = damage die of weapon + Strength modifier for thrown weapons + bonuses + penalties

The attack roll uses your unarmed proficiency bonus. As normal for ranged weapons, you do **not** add your Strength modifier to damage rolls unless the ability granting the unarmed attack says otherwise.

### Other Statistics

As pointed out by the unarmed attack rules, other statistics for an unarmed attack depend on the ability that grants it. This means the ability needs to indicate the range increment for a ranged unarmed attack.

#### Leshy Seedpod has a 10-foot range increment

The leshy's Seedpod feat was erroneously published without indicating the ranged unarmed attack's ranged increment. Paizo released a [clarification](https://paizo.com/community/blog/v5748dyo6sh3j?Pathfinder-Society-Character-Options) that that will be part of an upcoming errata.

> The seedpod ranged unarmed attack granted by the Seedpod feat (page 54) has a range increment (not a flat range) of 10 feet.